# How to define a ctor for a struct in F# that in turn calls the struct's default ctor

Tags: struct, constructor, f#

How do we define a ctor for an **immutable struct** in F#, that accepts only some of the fields. Or, compared to C# How do we **zero out the struct** (like by calling this() in the c# example below) in f# ?

**c#**

```
struct Point
{
    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly int _y;
    public Point(int x) : this() // Will zero the struct
    {
        _x = x;
    }
    public Point(int y) : this() // Will zero the struct
    {
        _y = y;
    }

}
```

The Point(x) ctor above zeros out the struct by calling this() and then sets a single field. This is what I am after. The following example is strongly simplified, the question is how to zero the struct and then set just a single field.

**f#**

```
type Point =
   struct 
      val X: float
      val Y: float

      new(x: float) = ? // how to zero out the struct and then set ONLY X ?

   end
```

Comment: Unlike C#, F# doesn't create default constructors automatically. If you define the default constructor as the primary constructor, you can call that from your specific constructor. (Not checked in code and not sure if that's the same for structs as for classes, thus not posted as answer.)

Comment: Thx for your input, but this does not solve it. Try it and you will find that it does not work out.

Comment: I believe that you cannot do this in F# because of syntax limitations. On the side note: Your C# struct will not compile because of 'already defines a member called 'Point' with the same parameter types' compiler error.

Comment: That is what I believe too, quite sure about. I filed already a language enhancement proposal. Thx for the heads up, removed the second new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the F# version of your C# code would be something like this

```
[<Struct>]
type Point =
  val mutable X: float
  val mutable Y: float

let p = Point(X = 1.0)
```

Although the struct members are mutable, `p` is not so you cannot set the members again.

```
// this will cause a compile error
p.X <- 2.0
```

Comment: Right, that is about what I use now, together with a factory class. Your reminder that the instance is not mutable anyway is a good one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Point(x, 0.0)` to call another constructor in the struct:

```
type Point =
   struct 
      val X: float
      val Y: float
      new(x: float, y: float) = { X = x; Y = y }
      new(x: float) = Point(x, 0.0)
   end
```

As a side-note, you can also declare a struct by using an ordinary `type` definition with the `Struct` attribute. This is certainly a matter of style, but I tend to prefer this variant:

```
[<Struct>]
type Point =
  val X: float
  val Y: float
  new(x: float, y: float) = { X = x; Y = y }
  new(x: float) = Point(x, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thx @Thomas, I reduced my example too much to make clear that this is not a solution for my problem: Actually I have a struct with explicit StructLayout. So 20 fields are all at offset 0, a low level DU so to say. Obviously I do not want to set the 20 fields from which only 1 is used. What I would like is to **zero out the struct** as the this() call in c# does and then set a single field.